# How to return null if the Mono is empty

Tags: java, spring, webflux

I am calling an external service to get `externalId`, in case of that service doesn't work, all what i need is just populate the value with `null`

```
return externalClient.getExternalId() //returns Mono<String> or Mono.empty()
                    .map(id -> {
                        //in case of empty stream, i need call entity.setExternalId(null);
                        entity.setExternalId(id);
                        return entity;
                    });
```

Comment: you could check the streams length with stream().count().
Which terminal operation do you use on the stream?

Comment: Its been awhile, but I thought there was an "empty" Mono, failing that you have two options as I see it, return an `Optional<T>` to indicate your method could return a value or not, or if its an error condition use `Error` i.e  `Mono.error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```java
return externalClient.getExternalId()
                     .map(id -> {
                        entity.setExternalId(id);
                        return entity;
                     })
                     .switchIfEmpty(() -> {
                        entity.setExternalId(null);
                        return Mono.just(entity);
                     });
```

Comment: the second solution will throw an exception
at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:246)

Comment: Thanks! The suggestion was removed (I don't use plain webflux for some time now).